How to start Celery Beat and Worker in production environment(cpanel)
please I developed a django app that automatically generates invoice and sends an email to client at certain hours. This app works perfectly in the development environment but not in production. I need help on how to work with redis and celery beat in production(cpanel)
When I tried starting celery beat on cpanel, i was getting an error regarding Redis
